# Using point sampling tool in Mapinfo Vertical Mapper?

Tags: mapinfo, vertical-mapper

I have series of points in Mapinfo. I need to extract elevation from a DEM for these points in Mapinfo. I point sampling tool in Qgis to do this . Unfortunately I don't have access to Qgis and need to do it in Mapinfo. I know that i need to do it in vertical mapper but unfortunately can not find it.

Answer (score 1):

Vertical Mapper can do this.

If you have a never 64 bit version of MapInfo Pro, you can also use the Point Inspection tool on the RASTER tab to do the same. This will however require a MapInfo Pro Advanced license, at least a trial license.

If you only have a few points, you can use the Info tool to inspect the DEM at the location of your points. If you have more than 10 it gets cumbersome.